# Jar cannot be opened on different Computer ("Can not find main class")

Tags: class, jar, program-entry-point

Today I programmed myself a Little game, which I compiled into a jar through Eclipse - I made sure its a executable jar, or runnable jar or however you want to call it.

I've sent the jar to a friend of mine, but oddly he's not able to open it.
He's always receiving the "Can not find main class" error, which shouldn't pop up since it works perfectly for me. I've already googled but was not able to find a answer.

If you're interested, you can take a look here, if it works for you:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-3939961/WidzDeluxe.jar.html

Now the question I have is kind of obvious I guess, is the error only for him or do you all have the same problem? What's the cause of it?

If people wish, I also upload the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have compiled class files bundled inside this jar with a different (higher) version of Java. Presumably it was Java 1.7 and the friend of yours is trying to open it with Java 1.6.

Here is the stacktrace I received trying to open your executable jar with Java 1.6.0_21:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: NewJFrame : Unsupported major.min
or version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: NewJFrame. Program will exit.
```

One possible solution that came to my ming would be to set the compliance level to let's say 6.0 in **Java Compiler** settings in Eclipse. That should to the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, found I was compiling the program for Java 1.7. I ended up updating Java on all my computers that I was running it on and it worked great.